# Breakpoints are not highlighting the entire line in Visual Studio 2013

Tags: visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, breakpoints

I recently installed the Update 2. So now when I put a breakpoint it just puts a red dot on the left side of the file, but it doesn't highlight the entire line. I am not sure if Update 2 changed the settings, but I thought so.

I tried this: in **Tools>Options>Debugger>General>Highlight entire source line for breakpoints and current statement (C++ only)**. So it tells that this doesn't work for C#. What should I do to highlight the entire line?

**UPDATE:**

[image]

Comment: It highlights the *statement* that will be hit. Are you trying to break on a lambda or curly brace or something similar?

Comment: @J.Steen There is no problem with breaking. When I put a break point when I am not debugging it usually highlighted the entire line, it is not doing that any more.

Comment: Yes, and I'm asking where you're putting the breakpoint, if anything has changed in *your* behaviour. Because it highlights statements for me. Probably a localised issue with your settings? =)

Comment: Yeah, can't reproduce, sorry to say.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same problem and it went away by closing VS 2013 and delete / rename following registry keywords:

> 12.0_Config 
>   12.0

in

> HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\

when restarting Visual Studio, the config settings dialog appeared and I selected not to import settings from previous version.

Breakpoints and current line while debugging were normal again :)

Comment: It disables a ton of extensions, but at least brings the highlight back

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem on visual studio 2012 and by following the instruction by McNos, I was able to resolve the problem.

In my case, I renamed the registry node 11.0 to 11.0-OLD and 11.0_Config to 11.0-Config-OLD under

HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\VisualStudio\

Restarted visual studio and it popped the config settings dialog...

Thanks McNos

Comment: This didn't work for me. Also it caused some of my add-ons to not show up, and I couldn't get them back without reverting the change. Beware of using this method.

Answer (score 0):

I could not find the configuration for VS2019. Then I searched a bit more and found that this command fixes the issue:

```
devenv.exe /updateconfiguration
```

Reference:
https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/debug-no-longer-highlights-current-line-yellow-lin/25156

Note: the problem started to happen after installing the lastest VS update.