# Breakpoint not fully highlighted when debugging

Tags: c#, visual-studio, debugging, breakpoints

I'm having a weird problem where breakpoints that are currently hit are not fully highlighted, which causes them to be only partially evaluated. See image below. The statement the debugger is on returns true. However, the debugger does not go past 'products' and thus it goes to the end of the if statement.  It can happen to any line of code regardless of length. Also, the point at which the highlighting drops off is random, sometimes it will only highlight the first letter.

Example:
[image]

I use Attach to Process (on all w3wp.exe instances) for this project. When not debugging the whole line is highlighted as it should be.

I have tried the following:

- Clean & ReBuild Project
- Deleting bin & obj folders and restarting VS
- Deleting all breakpoints and resetting one or two
- Restarting computer
- Deleting .SUO file
- Trying the solutions in this somewhat-similar [topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177870/breakpoints-are-not-highlighting-the-entire-line-in-visual-studio-2013)

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Breakpoints are not highlighting the entire line in Visual Studio 2013](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24177870/breakpoints-are-not-highlighting-the-entire-line-in-visual-studio-2013)

Comment: The question is similar but the answers there did not help me. Do you want me to delete this post? It's been a while, I think I forgot how SO works.

Comment: If it is a different problem, then you shouldn't have to delete it. I just marked as duplicate because it seemed similar.

Comment: When this has happened to me previously it was because I had the Symbol file (pdb's) path incorrect, therefore even although I was connecting to the running app I had just built, it was using the pdb's from another location, therefore another build of my application. Could be something worth checking, you can check from Debug -> Options -> Debugging -> Symbols.

Comment: Hmm, I saw that page in Options. I don't get what URL I should put in the path field. But I did try checking the Microsoft.Symbols.Server box but it didn't change anything. Sometimes if I do a apppool recycle and website restart, then retry the clean/rebuild, I will get "No Symbols loaded for this document" even though the Modules window shows w3wp.exe's symbols were successfully loaded.

Comment: I would assume that you aren't pointing to any incorrect pdb's from your description. Can you add a specific path to your pdb's, delete the pdb's that are in the same folder as your application then attempting to connect to it again. As you say you should be able to see in the debug output which symbols were loaded and from where.

Comment: Ok, here's what I did. I added a new folder location under the Symbol (.pdf) Locations in that Symbols option screen, and set it to my project's bin folder. I left the cache directory the same. I then reset IIS and cleaned/rebuilt the solution, and I am still getting the same problem. Screenshot: http://1drv.ms/1Gt1yv4 Should I create a different question for this, since at this point it's branched off to a different problem?

Comment: Within the `Modules` window can you see your project as being loaded with Symbols? Although I'm not fully familiar with w3wp worked applications I would expect your module should still load. It feels to me looking at your screenshot that when you are starting your application it is not the correct one you expect to be running when attempting to connect to it, this can be seen in the fact that you are now getting the message that no symbols loaded, process explorer is good for seeing what assemblies are loaded for that process.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This happens when Visual Studio is stepping through compiled code that **does not match** the source code displayed in the IDE. Among other things, the generated pdb tells VS how long an individual line of code is in order to properly highlight it on a breakpoint; the "incomplete highlighting" indicates that VS is executing a line of code *with a different length* than the actual line indicated. You need to completely clean and rebuild everything. I know you indicated that you tried that, but something is persisting or not being built correctly.

You can also try going to Debug > Options and Settings, checking "Require source files to exactly match the original version", and building/running again. This should be additional confirmation that there is a mismatch between what you're looking at and what's being compiled.

Comment: You are right. The source code is different from the original version. Now it makes sense. However, how do I sync the two versions? It doesn't seem to change after a clean and rebuild.

Comment: I accept your answer as it did answer my initial question. It's a good idea to keep that option checked so I can let VS update the source. I'm not sure when exactly VS updates the source but, surprisingly, I found that a simple Build worked after making changes, even though it didn't before. Not sure why it's better now. Thanks.

Comment: For people passing by here. I just saw this answer but I solved the problem with a different way. I closed VS, deleted the `.vs` folder at the solution level and also deleted the `obj` folders both in my test project and in my class library. Then I opened VS again and this time it would execute the correct source code.